# Separation of Al-Si alloys without electrolysis

Tags: metallurgy, extraction, alloy

Can pure (or roughly pure) $\ce{Al}$ be somehow thermally, chemically, or physically separated from the $\ce{Si}$ contained in an $\ce{Al-Si}$ alloy? How? Approximately what purity of Aluminum can be achieved in this way?

Comment: Have you checked the phase diagram?

Comment: Aluminium reacts with hydrochloric acid much more readily than silicon does so that might be an avenue to look into.